# Compiler error when putting class in App_Code folder for common use

Tags: class, compiler-construction, app-code

I have put a class in the App_Code folder, so it should be accessible for all my source files. Intellisense indeed sees the class (in code-behind), but when I run the site from the browser I get a compiler error:

```
**Compilation Error**

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'ClsTranslation' is not defined.
Source Error:
Line 38:     End If    
Line 39:     
**Line 40:     Dim clsTrans As ClsTranslation**  
Line 41:     clsTrans = New ClsTranslation()  
Line 42:     lblLevel0.Text = clsTrans.GetResource("", "Modules")  

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myproject\InfoSiteMap.aspx.vb    Line: 40
```

I am running this site as a web project and therefore the build-option `content/compile` for my `App_Code/class` is not available. I also tried to map the file to the pre-compiler using the `@` Reference directive, but this seems to work for user controls only and not for classes. Also tried to put the class in a namespace, all with same result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, when I do this, the build action of the file is to "Content" instead of "Compile". Highlight the class in solution explorer and hit f4 and change this.